# Uncaught ReferenceError is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

what Am I missing here?

I have this javascript in an html view:

```
 sections.forEach(sec => {
    const li = jQuery(`<li>${sec.categoryName}<button type="button" onclick="
    if (confirm('Remove ${sec.categoryName}?')) removeSectionTapped(sec)"
        >Remove</button></li>`);
        jQuery('#Sections').append(li);
    });

function removeSectionTapped(sec) {
    console.log(sec)
}
```

after I press OK on the confirm I get this error :  `Uncaught ReferenceError sec is not defined`

sec is defined in the confirm message but no inside the if statement..

Comment: All of that between the backticks is just a string. Don’t use inline event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables called `sec`, both of them are declared as the names of function arguments and so are local to those functions.

You are trying to use a variable inside an `onclick` attribute. This attribute is not inside either of those functions (even though the HTML source code from which the attribute is generated is) so the variable is out of scope by the time it is used.

Don't use `onclick` attributes, bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead.

```
 sections.forEach(sec => {
    const li = jQuery("<li />");
    li.append(sec.categoryName);
    const button = jQuery('<button type="button" />');
    button.text("Remove")
    button.on("click", () => {
        if (confirm(`Remove ${sec.categoryName}?`)) {
            removeSectionTapped(sec);
        }
    });
    li.append(button);
    jQuery('#Sections').append(li);
});

function removeSectionTapped(sec) {
    console.log(sec)
}
```